# Can I go back to the thread execution context?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, user-interface

I need to create a form on another thread, something like a splash screen when the application starts.

```
LoadingMyForm w = null;
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    try
    {
        w = new LoadingMyForm();
        w.Show();

        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        w.Close();
        w = null;
    }
});

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

This works for now, but to stop it I have to call `thread.Abort();` which will raise an exception, and when I catch that exception, as you can see, I close the window. Is there some kind of mechanism to get back on the thread execution context and just call the `Close` method on the form ?

As I understand :

```
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
```

keeps my thread alive, so at least, is it possible to assign other operations to be run on this thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a yet another way of doing this. Usage:

```
var splash = new SplashWindow();

// continue when the window is shown
splash.Start(() => new LoadingMyForm());

// do some initialization work
// ...

splash.Stop();
```

Implementation:

```
class SplashWindow
{
    CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    Thread _thread;

    // show window
    public void Start(Func<Window> createWindow)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(false);
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = _cts.Token;

        _thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            var window = createWindow();
            window.Loaded += (s, e) =>
            {
                // window is shown
                tcs.SetResult(true);
            };

            var dispather = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            dispather.InvokeAsync(() =>
                window.Show());

            using (token.Register(() =>
                dispather.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Normal),
                useSynchronizationContext: false))
            {
                Dispatcher.Run();
            }

            window.Close();
        });

        _thread.IsBackground = true;
        _thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        _thread.Start();
        tcs.Task.Wait();
    }

    // hide window
    public void Stop()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        _thread.Join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use your form's `Dispatcher` to do the work. The simplest call would be to do this:

```
w.Dispatcher.Invoke(w.Close);
```

... though you might want to add a method to your LoadingMyForm class that wraps the logic:

```
public void ThreadSafeClose()
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(Close);
}
```

You should note that, while this closes the Window safely, it will leave the `Thread` and `Dispatcher` still running - you may want to shut those down manually, but iut sounds from your question that you want to re-use the thread later anyway. Again, the `Dispatcher.Invoke` and `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` methods will help you here.